# How to merge instead of replace object when extend

Tags: javascript, inheritance, coffeescript, mixins

```
class A
  constructor:
    //dosomething
  loadFunctions:
    loadDrillingCharges: (memoize) ->


class B extends A
  constructor:
    super()
  loadFunctions:
    loadLockDDR: (memoize) ->
```

`(new B).loadFunctions` will be an object with `loadLockDDR` attribute only

I want the `(new B).loadFunctions` to be `{ loadDrillingCharges: -> , loadLockDDR: -> }`

I can `_.extend(B::loadFunctions, A::loadFunctions)` but it is not elegant.

I tried to use [cocktail mixin](https://github.com/onsi/cocktail) but it screw up the super()

What can I do to merge the object after extend and not screw up the coffescript super.

Comment: I would simply avoid this pattern, and use a prefix, which you're already doing with `load`.

Answer (score 1):

Mixins are not something supported natively by CoffeeScript, for the good reason that
they can be trivially implemented yourself. For example, here’s two functions,
extend() and include(), that’ll add class and instance properties respectively to a class:

```
extend = (obj, mixin) ->
 obj[name] = method for name, method of mixin 
 obj

include = (klass, mixin) ->
 extend klass.prototype, mixin

# Usage
include Parrot,
 isDeceased: true

(new Parrot).isDeceased
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sexy, but...

```
class A
  constructor: ->
    # dosomething
  loadFunctions: ->
    loadDrillingCharges: (memoize) ->


class B extends A
  constructor: ->
    super()
  loadFunctions: ->
    do (that=super()) ->
      that.loadLockDDR = (memoize) ->
      that

console.log (new A).loadFunctions()
console.log (new B).loadFunctions()
```

Producing:

```
{ loadDrillingCharges: [Function] }
{ loadDrillingCharges: [Function], loadLockDDR: [Function] }
```